# why does OpenSSH 6.x client send a string upon connection but 5.x does not?

Tags: linux, ssh

**TL;DR: Why does the ssh client for OpenSSH 6.x send the string "OpenSSH_6.2p2" immediately when connecting, and OpenSSH 5.x client does not send anything?**

---

I am trying to get an ssh tunnel working via an HTTP/S proxy.  I can get a TCP connection which is properly tunneled, using an http CONNECT request.  It works correctly with the SSH client on my Mac OSX 10.9, but does not work with an older Mac running an older OSX.

This led to the following oddity which I am at lost to explain.  (This may be a foolish question to someone familiar with the SSH protocol, but after searching for a bit I cannot find a simple explanation of what that protocol is supposed to look like, and am hoping to not have to read the entire RFC in order to debug this; thus this post.)

---

**On Mac OSX 10.9 with OpenSSH_6.2p2:**

Terminal 1:

```
nc -l 127.0.0.1 5000
```

Terminal 2:

```
ssh test@127.0.0.1 -p 5000
```

Terminal 1 then outputs:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2
```

So **this newer client transmitted that string upon connection.**

---

**On CentOS 6.3 with OpenSSH_5.3p1:**

Terminal 1 and 2 commands exactly the same as above.

But terminal 1 does not output anything.  **Looks like this older client didn't send anything upon connection.**

---

The TCP connection itself it working correctly from everything I can tell.  It seems to be a protocol difference.  But these are both apparently using SSH "version 2" protocol.

These two machines seems to be able to SSH to each other without trouble.  However there is something odd happening with my tunnel, and I'm trying to understand what the protocol is looking for so I can debug.

**Does anyone understand what is going on here?  Or perhaps know where there is a simple 1,2,3 type explanation of which side sends what for this protocol and any info on version differences?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's covered here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2

Both the client and the server are supposed to send their version strings upon connection.  However it appears that in the earlier versions the client is waiting for the server before sending it's string - which seems like an implementation detail that is technically a bug (presumably fixed in SSH 6.x) but doesn't normally create a problem in practice.

If anyone is interested, here is what I was trying to solve: https://github.com/bradleypeabody/proxyman/blob/master/README.md